# ExtJS - Ext.Msg box dynamic height and width

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have a message box that I create like so:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
  title: 'title',
  msg: 'some message',
  buttons: Ext.Msg.OKCANCEL,
  icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING
});
```

The message content is of variable length and sometimes it breaks into two lines. My requirement is to get the message into a single line so I hard-coded a width for the message box like so:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
      title: 'title',
      msg: 'some message',
      buttons: Ext.Msg.OKCANCEL,
      icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
      minWidth: 900,
      width: 900
    });
```

This increased the width of the box and my message could now fit into a single line for most cases which is sufficient for my requirements. However, this introduced a new problem.

[image]

As you can see, there is now an empty space that gets added to the bottom of the box. This space increases with each new entry if it is greater than a certain length ( I think this length is the original width calculated for the box by the framework).

What I think is happening is, the framework initially calculates a height and a width based on the data provided. But then the width gets overridden by the new value I set, increasing the horizontal length of the box. But as the height never gets adjusted accordingly, it is left at its initially calculated value, resulting in the above behavior.

Some help to sort this out would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

**Update:**
The ExtJS version in use is 4.1.1

Working fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kes)

Comment: Which version you are using ?

Comment: The extJS version is 4.1.1

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ker). What height you are talking about ?

Comment: Please check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kes) The behavior does not show in your example, because each message line would still remain in a single line for the initial widths/heights calculated by the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, when `show` method of `msgbox` is get called, one inner function `doAutoSize` called by framework but at that time our `width` (900) is not applied to `topContainer` (which contains msg part) of the `msgbox` that's why it is taking higher `height`.

To resolve this issue, we can call `setHeight` method after `show` method like below :-

```
msg.setHeight(msg.header.getHeight()+msg.topContainer.getHeight()+msg.bottomTb.getHeight());
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ker)

**Note:** For more details please go through `show` method of framework.

Hope this will help/guide you.